# pivot one column in pandas dataframe and create 4 new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm working with pandas dataframe. I have datafreme like:

```
    df
    COUNTRY   LINE    PRODUCT    SERVICE
    Argelia    1       1.0        Mobile
    Argelia    1       2.0        Mobile
    Argelia    1       3.0        Mobile
    Argelia    2       1.0        Mobile
    Argelia    3       2.0        Mobile
    Argelia    3       3.0        Mobile
```

I want to group by LINE and pivot PRODUCT column, but i need 4 product columns (product_1, product_2, product_3 and product_4), it don't care if there are any PRODUCT value = 4 or not.

I'm trying to use `get_dummies` with this code:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(dfs['PRODUCT'], prefix='product')], axis=1)
df.drop(['PRODUCT'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['COUNTRY', 'LINE', 'SERVICE']).agg({'product_1' : np.max, 'product_2': np.max, 'product_3':np.max, 'product_4':np.max}).reset_index()
```

But it give me only 3 columns of product, I want 4 columns to have this dataframe:

```
 COUNTRY    LINE   SERVICE   product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4
 Argelia     1     Mobile       1          1          1           0
 Argelia     2     Mobile       1          0          0           0
 Argelia     3     Mobile       0          1          1           0
```

Is it possible?

(I need to change PRODUCT values type 1.0 to 1 too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new columns with all possible products, here is alternative solution, I hope faster with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) for maximal `1` value, `rename` for convert floats columns to integers, [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and `reindex`:

```
cols = [f'product_{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['COUNTRY', 'LINE', 'SERVICE'],
                      columns='PRODUCT',
                      fill_value=0,
                      aggfunc='size')
        .clip(upper=1)
        .rename(columns=int)
        .add_prefix('product_')
        .reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
PRODUCT               product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4
COUNTRY LINE SERVICE                                            
Argelia 1    Mobile           1          1          1          0
        2    Mobile           1          0          0          0
        3    Mobile           0          1          1          0
```

In your solution use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, convert to integers, then aggregate by `max` and add `reindex`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.pop('PRODUCT').astype(int),prefix='product')], axis=1)
cols = [f'product_{i}' for i in range(1, 5)]
df = df.groupby(['COUNTRY', 'LINE', 'SERVICE']).max().reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
                      product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4
COUNTRY LINE SERVICE                                            
Argelia 1    Mobile           1          1          1          0
        2    Mobile           1          0          0          0
        3    Mobile           0          1          1          0
```